# Round robin scheduling program not producing correct result

Tags: java, algorithm, round-robin

I am struggling to visualize a simple Round Robin scheduling program which finds the average waiting time for a fixed number of processes that arrive at the server. The assumption is that I am given an array of arrival times, burst times and the quantum time (fixed time to service each process), which is sorted in ascending order of arrival times.

```
public float roundRobin (int n, int[] arrivalTimes, int[] runTimes, int quantumTime) {

    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(runTimes));
    int waitingTime = 0;

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int currentProcess = queue.poll();
        if (currentProcess > quantumTime) {
            int remaining = currentProcess - quantumTime;
            waitingTime += remaining;
            queue.add(remaining );
        }
    }

    return (float)waitingTime/n;
}
```

The above code does not produce the correct average waiting time when I try running it with sample inputs I found on the internet. Could someone please guide me on what I am doing wrong and how I can implement my result correctly? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I did a search for `arrivalTimes` and found only one match. That can't be good.

Comment: Could you better explain what this program is supposed to do? From my understanding, the waitTime = runTime - quantumTime. If runTime<= quantumTime then waitTime = 0. You want the average waitTime for the n processes. Correct?

Comment: @Adam Yes, that is my understanding as well. However, the article on this popular algorithms website (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-robin-scheduling-with-different-arrival-times/) states that `waitingTime = turnAroundTime - runTime = completionTime - (arrivalTime + runTime)`. I was hoping someone could shed light on whether I have the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

`int[]` is single object so you can't convert it to list via `Arrays.asList()` because it return `List<int[]>` but you need to create function to do this

```
public static List<Integer> asList(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
    for (int i : array)
        result.add(i);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. The easiest approach would be to simulate the process but you are missing a few key parts that will keep you from getting the correct solution.

- Your program doesn't look at the arrival times to determine when to add the processes to the queue.
- Your program isn't using the rest of the quantum time to execute another process
- Your program doesn't calculate wait time correctly. It needs to account for the wait time of every process in the queue except the one running.
- You program is looping through the queue. It would probably be easier if your program looped through time. At each time, you can simulate what processes are running.

I created a similar round robin program that should do what you are looking for.

```
//Use a class to keep track of the current processes status.
public class Process{
    public int burstTime;
    public int arrivalTime;
    public int completionTime;
    public int remainingRunTime;

    //Initialize processes with an arrival time and burst time
    public Process( int arrivalTimeValue , int burstTimeValue){
        burstTime = burstTimeValue;
        arrivalTime = arrivalTimeValue;
        completionTime = -1;
        remainingRunTime = burstTime;
    }
}

static public float roundRobin ( int[] arrivalTimes, int[] burstTimes, int quantumTime) {
    //Avoid divide by zero
    if(arrivalTimes.length == 0)
        return 0;

    //processes can be either arriving, running or finished
    List<Process> arrivingProcesses = new ArrayList<Process>();
    Queue<Process> runningProcesses = new LinkedList<Process>();
    List<Process> finishedProcesses = new ArrayList<Process>();

    //Create all processes in arriving
    for(int i = 0; i < arrivalTimes.length; i++){
        arrivingProcesses.add(new Process(arrivalTimes[i], burstTimes[i]));
    }
    //I assume the arrays already list the processes based on priority.
    // If there is another way you want to choose priority then you should sort arrivingProcesses


    int currentTime = 0;

    //Simulate time until the processes are all finished
    while(!(arrivingProcesses.isEmpty() && runningProcesses.isEmpty())){

        //First add any arriving processes to the queue
        for(int i = arrivingProcesses.size()-1; i>= 0; i--){
            if(arrivingProcesses.get(i).arrivalTime <= currentTime){
                runningProcesses.add(arrivingProcesses.get(i));
                arrivingProcesses.remove(i);
            }
        }

        //Run the first item in the queue
        if(!runningProcesses.isEmpty())
            runningProcesses.peek().remainingRunTime --;

        currentTime++;

        //finish process if run time is 0
        if(runningProcesses.peek().remainingRunTime == 0){
            runningProcesses.peek().completionTime = currentTime;
            finishedProcesses.add(runningProcesses.remove());
        }

        //if the quantum time is reached, put the process in the back
        if(currentTime%quantumTime == 0 && !runningProcesses.isEmpty()){
            runningProcesses.add(runningProcesses.remove());
        }

    }

    //Calculate total waiting time
    float totalWaitTime = 0;

    for(Process checkProcess : finishedProcesses){
        totalWaitTime += (checkProcess.completionTime - (checkProcess.arrivalTime + checkProcess.burstTime));
    }

    //return the average
    return totalWaitTime / arrivalTimes.length;

}
```

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for the program with your approach, it does make sense.
However, there is something unclear to me in the step where you add the arriving processes to the queue:
In the line `arrivingProcesses.get(i).arrivalTime <= i`, shouldn't this be `arrivingProcesses.get(i).arrivalTime <= quantumTime`?

Comment: Good catch. That line is supposed to determine if the process has arrived yet. If the arrival time is the current time, then the process is added to the queue.

Comment: That makes sense. But shouldn't the condition then be  `if(arrivingProcesses.get(i).arrivalTime == currentTime)`

Comment: `==` would work but I made it `<=` as safety. I don't want the loop to be infinite if a negative arrival time was given.